# Search in SQL where string starts with X

Tags: php, sql

Well i currently want to do a search engine with SQL and PHP. I crrently use the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM info WHERE name LIKE '%$q%' LIMIT 10
```

But i want to select the info with 'name' that start with $q, not the ones that cointain $q.

Comment: "I want to do a search engine", what does that mean? does it mean you want to execute a query?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Simply remove the first wildcard (%):

```
SELECT * FROM info WHERE name LIKE 'X%' LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to search fields that have multiple names and you want to search for a name that might be in the middle of the field, then it might be better to use `Full Text Search` (FTS). For example, if the `name` field in the OP refers to a full name and could contain `"John Doe"` and you want to search for `"Doe"`, then FTS is probably going to be better (more accurate and faster) than using a `LIKE` operator. With FTS, the individual words in text are indexed and so searches can be very fast, plus it allows for more complex searches such as the ability to find two words (or names) in a field that are not adjacent (to pick one example at random).

The specific database vendor is not mentioned in the OP, but if FTS is supported, then it might be a good choice for what you are attempting.  Some FTS [information for SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx) and [for MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) is easily found with a search.